# compact 1-0 array by group by functionality in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input of `1`,`0` array,
I would like to remove zeros and sum the continuous `1`s, like

input: `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`
output: `[2,1,1]`

I wrote this basic function that works (don't mind the awful code, just a draft)

```
def foo(arr):
    z_flag = False
    s = 0
    a = []
    for i in arr:
        if i != 0:
            s += 1
        else:
            z_flag = True
        if z_flag:
            z_flag = False
            if s > 0:
                a.append(s)
            s = 0
    if s > 0:
        a.append(s)

    return a
```

I would like to do it much faster, preferably replace the loop with `numpy` internal functionality

will appreciate any suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For decent to large arrays

With `a` as the input array/list, we can do -

```
# Compare against 1 to get a mask. Append on either sides with False
# so that when do consecutive comparison next, we will catch the
# transitions including leading and trailing islands that might be 
# starting at the first element of the array or ending as the last one. 
# These transitions are signal the start and end of each island of 1s.
m = np.r_[False,np.asarray(a)==1,False]
idx = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1]!=m[1:])

# After catching those start,end indices, simply subtract between start
# and end indices to get island lengths. That's our o/p.
out = idx[1::2]-idx[::2]
```

If `a` is already an array, we can also use `a.astype(bool)` in place of `np.asarray(a)==1`.

Sample run -

```
In [81]: a
Out[81]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

In [82]: m = np.r_[False,np.asarray(a)==1,False]
    ...: idx = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1]!=m[1:])
    ...: out = idx[1::2]-idx[::2]

In [83]: out
Out[83]: array([2, 1, 1])
```

#### Solution for small-sized arrays

If you are working wtih `small-sized arrays` (100 or so elements), it's better to stick to loops. So, with that in mind, here's a solution -

```
def foo2(a):
    out = []
    island_started = False
    m = a.astype(bool)
    for i,m_i in enumerate(m):
        if m_i:
            if island_started==0:
                start = i
                island_started = True
        elif island_started==1:
            out.append(i-start)
            island_started = False      
    if m_i:
        out.append(i+1-start)
    return out
```

Timings against original solution -

```
In [223]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,2,(20))

In [224]: %timeit foo(a)
     ...: %timeit foo2(a)
6.65 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.9 µs ± 97.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [225]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,2,(30))

In [226]: %timeit foo(a)
     ...: %timeit foo2(a)
9.79 µs ± 331 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3.76 µs ± 63.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [227]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,2,(100))

In [228]: %timeit foo(a)
     ...: %timeit foo2(a)
32.3 µs ± 685 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
9.94 µs ± 257 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For further optimization, we can port this loopy solution to [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: excellent solution! thx, can you provide some farther explanation

Comment: @shahaf Added few comments.

Comment: although this is the solution I asked for, it seems that it has worst running time `38.8 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` yours compare to `1.29 µs ± 32.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
` mine...

Comment: @shahaf That's the usual cavaet with NumPy. It's meant for decent to large arrays, not such small ones. Is your actual dataset of just 10 elements?

Comment: I did timing as well, once the array was in the range of thousands, this solution worked the best.

Comment: @shahaf Added an optimized one for small arrays and timings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, I haven't timed it against yours but might be closer to what you're looking for

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
# Convert the array to a string of 1s and 0s
a = ''.join([str(x) for x in a])
# Split on the 0s to 'remove them'
a = a.split('0')
# Count the length of the arrays that are greater than 0
b = [len(x) for x in a if len(x) > 0]
print(b)
```

Output :`[2, 1, 1]`

Comment: timed it against mine, it preforms worst... (I think due to string manipulation)